# Join another table with MAX date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.dbPatID,
    p.dbpatfirstname,
    p.dbPatLastName,
    s.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchDetailType,
    t.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchTypeType,
    ISNULL(r.dbStatusDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbStatusDesc,
    ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeCode, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeCode,
    ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeDesc,
    p.dbProgRvw,
    ISNULL(s.dbSchDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbSchDate,
    ISNULL(s.dbSchTypeCnt, '0') AS dbSchTypeCnt,
    p.age,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbRecDate,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecType, '-') AS dbRecType,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecCom, '-') AS dbRecCom,
    a.dbPatApptTime AS LastVisitDate,
    a.dbSchTypeDesc AS LastVisitDesc
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN vw_ReferralKPIs r
    ON p.dbpatid = r.dbPatID
        AND r.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN SchDetail s
    ON s.dbPatCnt = p.dbPatCnt
        AND s.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN SchTypes t
    ON s.dbSchTypeCnt = t.dbSchTypeCnt
        AND t.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN Recalls rc
    ON p.dbpatcnt = rc.dbpatcnt
        AND rc.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN Appointments a
    ON p.dbpatcnt = a.dbpatcnt
        AND rc.ClientRef = a.ClientRef
        AND dbPFStatus = 1
WHERE (
        r.dbStatusDesc IN ('')
        OR '' = ''
        )
    AND s.dbSchDate <= GetDate()
    AND p.ClientRef = 'EPS'
    AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharged'
    AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'TC Disch'
    AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharge FTA'
```

I've added the Appointments join code as we need `LastVisitDate` and `LastVisitDesc` but we only wish to bring back the row from `Appointments` that has the max date (latest date).

If I add a temp Where clause `AND p.dbPatCnt = 9678`, it brings back 12 rows (all that person's appointments where `dbPFStatus` = 1). I only want to bring back the row that has the latest date.

[I've found a similar problem/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254760/joining-with-max-date-from-table) but am unclear on how to apply it to my code

thanks

Following on from that link I now have...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        p.dbPatID,
        p.dbpatfirstname,
        p.dbPatLastName,
        s.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchDetailType,
        t.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchTypeType,
        ISNULL(r.dbStatusDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbStatusDesc,
        ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeCode, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeCode,
        ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeDesc,
        p.dbProgRvw,
        ISNULL(s.dbSchDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbSchDate,
        ISNULL(s.dbSchTypeCnt, '0') AS dbSchTypeCnt,
        p.age,
        ISNULL(rc.dbRecDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbRecDate,
        ISNULL(rc.dbRecType, '-') AS dbRecType,
        ISNULL(rc.dbRecCom, '-') AS dbRecCom,
        -- New columns
        ca.LastVisitDate,
        ca.LastVisitDesc
FROM    Patient p
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_ReferralKPIs r ON p.dbpatid = r.dbPatID
                                     AND r.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN SchDetail s ON s.dbPatCnt = p.dbPatCnt
                               AND s.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN SchTypes t ON s.dbSchTypeCnt = t.dbSchTypeCnt
                              AND t.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN Recalls rc ON p.dbpatcnt = rc.dbpatcnt
                              AND rc.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    MAX(a.dbPatApptTime) AS LastVisitDate,
                            MAX(a.dbSchTypeDesc) AS LastVisitDesc,
                            a.dbpatcnt
                  FROM      appointments a
                  WHERE     a.dbPFStatus = 1
                            AND a.clientref = 'EPS'
                  GROUP BY  a.dbpatcnt
                ) ca ON ca.dbpatcnt = p.dbpatcnt
WHERE   --(
          --r.dbStatusDesc IN ( '' )
          --OR '' = ''
        --) AND 
        s.dbSchDate <= GETDATE()
        AND p.ClientRef = 'EPS'
        AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharged'
        AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'TC Disch'
        AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharge FTA';
```

This brings back the expected row count and correct LastVisitDate but the LastVistDesc is wrong. I've tried it without the Max and included it in the Group By but this produces a lot of duplicate rows.

thanks,

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Having the main WHERE clause reference tables that are in a LEFT OUTER JOIN , makes them become INNER JOIN.  So either you want the LEFT OUTER JOIN, move the main where clauses up to the individual JOIN clauses or change the LEFT OUTER to INNER.  It will increase performance.  Other comment is the GROUP BY that you have will also cause performance issues, just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.dbPatID,
    p.dbpatfirstname,
    p.dbPatLastName,
    s.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchDetailType,
    t.dbSchTypeCnt AS SchTypeType,
    ISNULL(r.dbStatusDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbStatusDesc,
    ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeCode, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeCode,
    ISNULL(t.dbSchTypeDesc, 'No Ref') AS dbSchTypeDesc,
    p.dbProgRvw,
    ISNULL(s.dbSchDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbSchDate,
    ISNULL(s.dbSchTypeCnt, '0') AS dbSchTypeCnt,
    p.age,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecDate, '1899-12-30') AS dbRecDate,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecType, '-') AS dbRecType,
    ISNULL(rc.dbRecCom, '-') AS dbRecCom,
    a.dbPatApptTime AS LastVisitDate,
    a.dbSchTypeDesc AS LastVisitDesc
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN vw_ReferralKPIs r
ON p.dbpatid = r.dbPatID
    AND r.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN SchDetail s
ON s.dbPatCnt = p.dbPatCnt
    AND s.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN SchTypes t
ON s.dbSchTypeCnt = t.dbSchTypeCnt
    AND t.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN Recalls rc
ON p.dbpatcnt = rc.dbpatcnt
    AND rc.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN Appointments a
ON p.dbpatcnt = a.dbpatcnt
    AND rc.ClientRef = a.ClientRef
    AND dbPFStatus = 1
WHERE (
    r.dbStatusDesc IN ('')
    OR '' = ''
    )
AND s.dbSchDate <= GetDate()
AND p.ClientRef = 'EPS'
AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharged'
AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'TC Disch'
AND r.dbStatusDesc != 'Discharge FTA'
AND a.dbPatApptTime = (SELECT MAX(a2.dbPatApptTime)
   FROM Appointment a2
   WHERE a2.ClientRef = a.ClientRef
    AND a2.dbPFStatus = 1)
```

Comment: This would break the LEFT JOIN on the appointment table, so that would need to be moved out of the main WHERE clause and into the appointment JOIN clause

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to write a Table-Value function that would return the data with input parameters of ClientRef and dbpacnt.  Then you could include the function within the select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LastAppointment]
    ( @clientRef INT,
      @dbpatcnt INT
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    ( SELECT TOP 1
                a.dbPatApptTime AS LastVisitDate,
                a.dbSchTypeDesc AS LastVisitDesc
      FROM      Appointments a
      WHERE     ClientRef = @clientRef
                AND Dbpatcnt = @dbpatcnt
                AND dbPFStatus = 1
      ORDER BY  a.dbPatApptTime)

GO
```

Then change

```
LEFT JOIN Recalls rc
    ON p.dbpatcnt = rc.dbpatcnt
        AND rc.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
LEFT JOIN Appointments a
    ON p.dbpatcnt = a.dbpatcnt
        AND rc.ClientRef = a.ClientRef
        AND dbPFStatus = 1
```

To

```
LEFT JOIN Recalls rc
    ON p.dbpatcnt = rc.dbpatcnt
        AND rc.ClientRef = p.ClientRef
CROSS APPLY dbo.LastAppointment (rc.ClientRef, p.dbpatcnt)
```